# java extract address items by regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string:
*user1:password@192.168.1.3:3306/dbname1*
and I need to fill the username, password, host, port and dbname variables...
my code:

```
String patternStr = "(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+):([A-Z]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+):([0-9]{1,5})/([A-Z0-9_-]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(dbpath);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Output:

```
false
```

:( show me my mistake please...
Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need a RegEx here?

Comment: @adarshr: +1 agree, regex adds unnecessary complexity here.

Comment: it seems that you are right - it is not needed :) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fix to your immediate problem.  Substitute

```
\b
```

with

```
\\b
```

Backslashes need to be escaped in Java.  I tried it with this:

```
"(\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+):([A-Z]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+):([0-9]{1,5})/([A-Z0-9_-]+)"
```

And your code printed `true`.

Comment: +1 for solving OP's problem as opposed to providing a different solution (as I did.) Even though I prefer my approach, there's something to be said for fixing problems!

Comment: @glow: I prefer your approach too, though it's easy to get bogged down in cases like this where there are dozens of approaches you *could* take.

Comment: There are four completely different good answers here and not one bad answer. Cool

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much simpler version that's not 100% correct, but it does the Job in your case:

```
String dbpath = "user1:password@192.168.1.3:3306/dbname1";
String patternStr = "([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^/]+)/(.+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(dbpath);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());

// Output: true
```

Comment: +1 This is the best one so far. But I would wrap it with anchors for good measure: i.e. `^([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^/]+)/(.+)$`

Comment: @ridgerunner Matcher.matches() does that. it's a full match, not a find

Answer (score 3):

```
class AddressRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dbpath = "user1:password@192.168.1.3:3306/dbname1";       

        // I should point out my coworker is wrong when he says this is a
        // guy eating too big a sandwich!! It's just a set of delimiters!
        String[] tokens = dbpath.split(":|@|/");

        String user = tokens[0];
        String host = tokens[1];
        String port = tokens[2];
        String dbid = tokens[3];

        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(host);
        System.out.println(port);
        System.out.println(dbid);


    }

}
```

Comment: But `:|@|/` is better written: `[:@/]`

Comment: @ridgerunner as far as I'm aware that's just a matter of taste. Is there any performance or functionality difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "user1:password@192.168.1.3:3306/dbname1";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("[:@/]");
String user = scanner.next();
String password = scanner.next();
String host = scanner.next();
int port = scanner.nextInt();
String dbName = scanner.next();
```